# while uploading file, handlers are not calling in EXT JS

Tags: extjs

While trying to upload the same file (on select) immediately more than one time, its not working but uploading a different file immediately, working fine. issue is happening in In IE and chrome browsers.

Note: Drag and Drop is working fine facing the problem with on select and below is the code

```
var comp = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {
    id : 'fileid',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    width : 0,
    buttonText : '',
    accept : ".xlsx,.xls",
    buttonOnly : true,
    listeners : {
        change : {
            element : 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
            fn : function() {
                abc(document.getElementById('fileid-button-fileInputEl').files[0],xyz);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Could anyone suggest on this.Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Reset your `filefield` before uploading a same file will solve this issue. In my example, I create a different button. When I click on this button, the value of file field is reset and then call to click event.

This is my [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vo6)